# jquery css('left', ... ) position bug?

Tags: jquery

With jquery I wrote the following highly complex code:

```
val = 100;
n.css('left', val /* + 'px' */);
console.log(val, n.css('left'));
```

The console output of it is:

```
100, "90px"
```

why is that so...?

Thanks in advance for some help

EDIT:
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RaznH/1/
You need to have your browser zoomed out (e.g. with "ctrl -") and the console opened in order to have the effect appear

Comment: And when i tried ..its `100 "auto"` `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/VqH9x/

Comment: It depends on the CSS. We need a fiddle or at least more code to explain it.

Comment: Example : http://jsbin.com/ogodiz/1/edit

Comment: @pXL -- Same with me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBMdS/ -- Chrome

Comment: I just tried with a jsfiddle. There it works perfect, even tried it with computed styles etc -.- I'm gonna upload the whole project... (failed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RaznH/1/)

Comment: Oh no, it works! But it's about the browser zoom! Zoom out a bit and see for yourself, the .css('left') takes browser zoom into account, for whatever reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well it seems like a webkit bug, the actualy jquery ticket is here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4993 and the bug report for webkit is here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105979

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `position` other than static (relative,absolute or fixed) declared on your element or else it won't work.

Taking the example from the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/VqH9x/1/ everything works fine when you declare a proper position.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use that. Instead, use:

```
.offset().left
```

So, you would be having this code:

```
console.log(val, n.offset().left);
```

Or may be for your question, it is based on the browser, which interprets it **relative to the document**.

From **jQuery API**:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.